# Security and sessions

Tags: php, security, session

I've ready a couple of articles about the security of session, but I haven't seen anything that specifically touches upon my specific piece of code.  I am super paranoid about the security of my site because it has sensitive information.

Everyone of my pages starts with this line of code:

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["username"]))
{
header("Location: login.html");
}
```

Is this secure enough?  I am new to PHP but the more I read, the more I am more paranoid.  Can someone simply set a session called username and make it look like it's been set by my site to gain access?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about security and would be better suited for [security.se] or [codereview.se]

Comment: Everything you need to know -> https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: just because session data is kept server-side doesn't mean much for security. Now it's reduced to being as secure as your server is. And if your oponent is the NSA, you might as well give up and leave everything wide open.

Comment: @MarcB Saying that "it's reduced to being as secure as your server is" is essentially always true.  You can do whatever you want with SSL, CSRF protections, amazing PRNGs, but if you have SSH open to the world with a root password of 'password' you are still going to get owned, so i don't see what value your comment brings.  Assuming the php session key that is generated and stored in the cookie is random and sent over a secure connection, checking the value in the session on the server would be a trusted source of information - the OP is not going to get much better.

Answer (score 2):

`$_SESSION` values are purely server-side can cannot be tampered with from the client.

Its difficult to say what other problems you might face as this is only part of your login system and there are many other issues that can trip you up.

One problem that we *can* see is that in the fail case you're only setting the `header`, and not stopping the script afterwards (eg with `die()`). Any code that is under that `if` statement will still get executed even if the user isn't logged on, so if you have any actions in there the user can execute them without any authentication at all.